# How to add home folder to user without one

Tags: jenkins, lxc, ssh-copy-id

I have a `lxc` container. I connect to it with `sudo lxc-attach 100` which works fine. but I want to use it as a deployment target for jenkins (I know that I could use docker, but I haven't gotten that setup yet).

I have created a user **jenkins** with **www-data** as primary group using the command  `useradd -g www-data jenkins` which works fine, but there is no folder in **/home** which means that I am in doubt of where I should put the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file with the public key of the ssh key of my Jenkins server.

I am aware that I could assign the user a password and log in using that and `ssh-copy-id` to push the key and then disallow password logins via SSH but I need to do this for several items and copy pasting (for now) seems easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I ought to have provided the `-d, --home HOME_DIR` parameter.

I looked at the man page for `useradd` and `usermod` and discovered that I could supply the `-d` parameter to the `usermod` command as well...
I did so and the result was

> usermod: no changes

Baffled, I  did `su jenkins` and `cd` which resulted in

> sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/jenkins

I went back to my root prompt and created the directory
`mkdir /home/jenkins && chown jenkins:www-data /home/jenkins`

and now it seems to work as I expected.